# set env variables in systemd according to content of the file

Tags: systemd

Is it possible to set env variables in systemd units according to content of the file. Something like ENV=`cat somefile`?

I need to set path to the executable file according to content of somefile. I didn't find any info about variables in systemd ,exept env variables so I try to use them, but with no luck

I've tried to use Environment = 'ENV=`cat somefile`' but with no luck. It just set the value of the variable to `cat somefile`. I've tried to use `cat` and `/bin/cat` but result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special directive exactly for this purpose: `EnvironmentFile`. You should put it into your `[Service]` section like this:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/somefile
```

If the file isn't there the service won't start, so to be able to start it despite the presence of the file you can add leading **-** sign in front of the file name, like:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/somefile
```

Be aware, that although this file looks like `shell script` it's not and behaviour of variables declaration sligtly differs, in particular, you can't reference other variables in the declaration of the variable.

Please, read [EnvironmentFile](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=) and [Environment](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment=) options description for more details. [Command lines](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) could be helpfl too.